# Animation of image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have a `scrollview` and `imageview` subviewed to `scrollview`.on a button click I `subview` another `imageview` and sent that image to the back of that existing image by

```
[nextImageView sendSubviewToBack:firstImageView];
```

and i want the `firstImageView` to fade  and show the second image on a button click and on the button click i want the reverse also to be happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tuning the answer of @jhilgert00.....

```
-(IBAction)toggleImage:(id)sender {

     if (img1.alpha==1)
     {

     [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1 // <--  Number of seconds 
                     animations:^{
                     img1.alpha = 0; 
                     img2.alpha = 1;

                     }];
     }
     else
     {
      [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1 // <--  Number of seconds 
                     animations:^{
                     img1.alpha = 1; 
                     img2.alpha = 0;

                     }];     



     }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, From what I understand you want to 'toggle' a couple images in and out on a button click. Try the following, where "img1" is the first UIImageView, and "img2" in the second UIImageView. This is called an [animation block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).

```
-(IBAction)showSecondImg:(id)sender {

     // Some code to add Img2 subview behind Img1..

     [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1 // <--  Number of seconds 
                     animations:^{
                     img1.alpha = 0; // <-- fade out in 1 second and shows Img2 below it
                     //add other animations here, like background color, etc. if needed.
                     }
     ];
}

-(IBAction)showFirstImg:(id)sender {

          // gradually fades the first UIImageView back on top
         [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1 
                         animations:^{
                         img1.alpha = 1;
                         }
         ];
    }
```